# SharePoint 2010 workflows not loading in SharePoint 2016

Tags: designer-workflow, upgrade-sharepoint, workflow-settings

Recently upgraded farm from 2010 to 2016.  Still using 2010 workflows, but the migration apparently did not do well for our custom ones.  These workflows appear to start up but do not assign tasks to approvers.  I've tried to load them in Designer 2013 but it just opens a page saying Designer cannot display the item.  There's also the concern that my Visio version being 2016 will cause a problem with it.  Should I just scrap all these old workflows and move on to the 2016 workflow platform, or is there a way to fix the 2010 ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to do some things...

First install all the recent updates for SharePoint Designer, there are some bug fixes in the last two sp1 upgrades

have you installed the Infopath service ? workflows 2010 require it as the workflows 2010 contain infopath forms

After that if your sharepoint designer is still displaying errors then i would remove all the cache and stop SP Designer from catching data.

and after that i would stat to check if SP designer is running into compatibility issues, i had one with SP designer and Visual studio 2015, i had to

- Unistall visual studio
- Unistall Sharepoint designer
- install sharepoint designer
- install sharepoint designer SP1 update
- install all sharepoint designer patches
- install visual studio again

after that check if your lists have the correct workflow associations

go to your list in SP designer
go to the list and check the workflows,
if you have missing workflow click on the workflow box and then click at the ribbon button "Associate existing workflows"

Comment: Yeah I have visual studio 2017.  The installer for SP1 says the expected version of the product was not found on the system.  Given that, I'm not sure if I even want to proceed with this.  Do you think it's about an equivalent amount of effort to just install the 2016 version of workflows?  Can that live on the same server as SharePoint?

Comment: to me looks like your SharePoint designer is bugged, i would reinstall SP designer.

sharepoint 2016 supports natively workflows 2010, i think reinstalling SP Designer will fix the  bug

There are no 2016 workflows, only 2013 and to run 2013 you have to install workflow foundation

Comment: Read my question to mean the 2013 version.  I think I can install it on the sharepoint server according to some site.  Anyway I reinstalled spd 2013 again and SP1 still wouldn't install over it. I don't see any concrete logs about the installation failure and I'm not excited about tearing apart my computer over this.  I'd rather just go with the 2013 workflows if it's not gonna work.

Comment: I eventually had to add PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1 to the installers on the command line because we had group policy preventing it from creating a system restore point